# What's the meaning of “conosophes”?

Tags: sens

In this [link](http://www.libertepolitique.com/Actualite/Editorial/Le-Brexit-et-les-conosophes), I find the word “conosophes”. What is its meaning?

Comment: La sagesse de l'origine du monde?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"conosophe" n'a d'entrée dans aucun dictionnaire. Selon l'article, ce mot fut prononcé pour le première fois par **Georges Pompidou** (Président de la République française, 1969 - 1974).
Il s'agit d'un **mot valise**, combinant "philosophe" et "con", et qui semble désigner le contraire d'un philosophe.
Dans la **biographie de Georges Pompidou d'Eric Roussel**, ce mot apparait une fois, désignant des "**intellectuels phraseurs**".

Quel est le sens précis de ce mot? Il y a trop peu d'éléments pour le cerner précisément, mais on peut affirmer qu'un conosophe désigne :

- Une personne.
- Cette personne exprime des idées
- Il y a une forte valeur négative sur la qualité des idées exprimées.

Si on reprend le terme "intellectuels phraseurs", on peut avancer qu'un conosophe est un intellectuel discutant d'idées absurdes, déplacées, inutiles, vides, etc. **L'intellectuel qui parle plus qu'il ne dit**.

Si on s'attarde plus sur l'article en lui même, il semble indiquer des intellectuels exprimant des **opinions ou des idées manquant gravement d'objectivité** car elles *"relève d’un certain aveuglement, voire de l’idéologie pure et simple."*.
En l'occurrence, le manque d'objectivité vient d'un problème de paradigme

Pour rappel, ce mot, à l'exception de cet article et de la biographie de Pompidou, semble ne pas exister.

Comment: Accessoirement, on pourrait supposer que ce genre de personne soit friand d'_amphigouris_

Comment: @Blue_Elephant : je viens d'apprendre le mot, merci :)

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble qu'il s'agit d'un néologisme (ou en tout cas mot inventé pour l'occasion) dérivé des mots *connerie* et *philosophie*.

Un conosophe, donc, serait  une personne faisant des raisonnements "philosophiques" en se basant sur des arguments complètement "cons".

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a pun, 'con' (in this case: 'stupid', 'dumb') + the end of 'philosophe' ('philosopher').

Answer (score 2):

*Philo* aimer, *Sophia* sagesse.

On peut aimer la sagesse et savoir en parler sans l'écrire comme Socrate : son discours se fait dans le moment sensible et singulier, l'*ici et maintenant*, c'est le domaine du Verbe... qui devient *blabla* quand il passe à l'écrit, car il manque au lecteur et le contexte et l'écoute attentive du philosophe qui réagira en fonction de ce qu'il perçoit de celui à qui il parle.

Le *conosophe* est d'une autre espèce, il parle de sagesse, mais sans n'y rien comprendre. Il est sûr et certain de son bon droit et de son savoir.
Il croit être sage par les mots mais sa conduite est celle d'un insensé, de quelqu'un qui vit dans ses chimères, ses propos sont approximatifs, voire incohérents ... on ne peut être plus loin de la réalité que le philosophe cherche à appréhender.

Que Georges Pompidou, le plus lettré des présidents de la V<sup>e</sup> République, se soit amusé à créer un néologisme pour éloigner ou décrire un fâcheux n'a rien d'étonnant quand on se souvient de la malice que son sourire et son regard pouvaient porter sur le monde.